# Open source PDF renderer for .NET?

Tags: .net, pdf

Is there an open source .NET library that can render PDFs to images (for server-side processing)? I know of [PDFsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/Default.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1), AFAIK it can only create and process PDFs, not render them.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511665/converting-pdf-to-images

Comment: Are you looking for something that is compatible with a particular open source license or a "free as in beer" product?

Comment: For the time being, it doesn't matter, but of course I'd prefer a permissive licence like LGPL or MIT.

Comment: And the close votes for this (9 year old) question is the reason I am no longer active on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) and [GhostScript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) can be used together to do this, both open source.

Matt Ephraim made a nice wrapper for Ghostscript in C# [here](http://www.mattephraim.com/blog/2009/01/06/a-simple-c-wrapper-for-ghostscript/).

All the processing I've done is on client-side, but PDFCreator supposedly has server capabilities described [here](http://en.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator)

UPDATE:
PDFCreator Server capabilities are briefly described [HERE](http://thefreewarejunkie.com/2008/02/network-admin-tip-create-shared-pdf.html).

Comment: +1: GhostScriptSharp is awesome.

Comment: @MattEphraim I think your wrapper violates on the AGPL license of ghostscript. You should probably verify this and clarify in the readme file on github.

Answer (score 1):

Foxit may work for someone else, but this question is about open source.
Joey's answer looks promising and leads me to
[Introducing GhostscriptSharp](http://www.mattephraim.com/blog/2009/07/08/introducing-ghostscriptsharp/)

Answer (score 0):

iTextsharp is very good.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Comment: To me it seems that it can only create PDFs, not render them. Just like PdfSharp. Is this a wrong impression?

Comment: I believe I misread the question are you looking to display a pdf in a form?

Comment: Yes, itextsharp does a lot of things, and does them well, but rendering is not one of the things it does. Great for grabbing existing text and form data, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FoxIt's SDK to render a PDF to a device context. They have a [DLL for win/linux](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/sdk/dll/) and [an ActiveX](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/sdk/activex/). See their [programmer's guide](http://foxit.vo.llnwd.net/o28/pub/foxit/manual/enu/FoxitPDF_SDK20_Guide.pdf). You'll see some relevant entries in the TOC in the first few pages.